# Use the subtype of a class in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I'm trying to use the generic type of a class in another class that uses this one:

**Kotlin**

```
class Callback <O> () 

class Controller <E> (callback: E) where E: Callback<O> {
    fun foo1 (a: O) {...}
    fun foo2 (): O {...}
}
```

**Java**

```
class Callback <O> {}

class Controller <E extends Callback<O>> {
    Controller(E callback) {}
    public void foo1(O a) {...}
    public O foo2() {...}
}
```

An easy solution is to declare both types E and O on the Controller class in this way:

**Kotlin**

```
class Controller <E, O> (callback: E) where E: Callback<O> { ... }
```

**Java**

```
class Controller <E extends Callback<O>, O> { ... }
```

However, I want to avoid to declare both types on the constructor because the information is repeated and it is not so pretty.

## Edit

I need the type `E` on the constructor because I need to define functions such as:

```
class StringCallback: Callback<String>() { ... }

fun example(callbackParam: Controller<StringCallback>) { ... }
```

I want the object `callbackParam` uses my defined `StringCallback`, not any `Callback<String>`.

And remember that I also need the `O` type in the`Controller` class to operate with this type. Can I "extract" or "infer" it without declaring it in the generic constructor?

[@LppEdd with your permission I'll use your class :) ]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you post a complete class? It doesn't need to be correct, I just want to see your "vision"

Comment: I mean, the function you defined here is perfectly fine. It will accept only StringCallback, in this case.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that if I do like that, in the `Controller` class I can't use the object type `O` which I know that is a String. Do you understand the problem, or do you need more info?

Comment: So basically you need access to the generic type of Callback, right? You might need to have a method which has a return type equals to that generic type, right?

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but  if that's the case than you **already** have access to it. I mean, look at the two methods (foo1 and foo2) of the Controller class I posted, they have access to E (**that you can also call O**), which is String.

Comment: So basically you need access to the generic type of Callback, right? **yes**
You might need to have a method which has a return type equals to that generic type, right? **yes**

Comment: I see your example and it is a good idea, but it not serves to me, because what I need is a function like `fun example()` which requires a `Controller<StringCallback>` as a parameter, not a `Controller<String>`.

I need this because I want to accept only **my** `StringCallback`, not any `Callback<String>`.

Comment: Would that function be inside the Controller class, or where? Anyway, I think a complete stub of the wanted result is better. Then I can answer you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is

```
class Controller<E> {
    private final Callback<E> callback;

    Controller(final Callback<E> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void foo1(final E a) { callback.set(a); }
    public E foo2() { return callback.get(); }
}
```

Example:

```
final Controller<String> stringController = new Controller<>(new Callback<>());
```

That's because you already know you'll accept a `Callback<?>`.
There is no need to use `E extends Callback`. But keep reading

This

```
Controller(final Callback<? extends E> callback)
```

means the constructor will accept every type which is a subtype  of `Callback<E>`

```
class StringCallback extends Callback<String> { ... }
class IntegerCallback extends Callback<Integer> { ... }

final Controller<String> c1 = new Controller<>(new StringCallback());
final Controller<Integer> c2 = new Controller<>(new IntegerCallback());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer LppEdd! However I need the generic type to be in the constructor. I edited the question to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the type of the `Callback` just that it's generic parameter is `E`.

So you can declare your class in Kotlin like this:

```
class Controller<O>(callback: Callback<O>) { ... }
```

And in java like this:

```
public class Controller<O> {
    public Controller(Callback<O> callback) { ... }
}
```

Declaring the type of the `Callback` to be generic would only make sense if you'd allow the caller of your controller to explicitly interact with the callback. But from your given code you just return or accept values from / to the callback.

Comment: I'd rename `E` to `O` as in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Lino! However I need the generic type to be in the constructor. I edited the question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You may shorten the code:

```
class Controller<E : Callback<O>, O> (callback: E) { .. }
```

But it will not let you a chance to get rid of the second generic parameter. You use the `O` type in the functions of your class.

You may try to say `class Controller<E: Callback<*>>` or `class Controller<E : Callback<Any>>` if you do not need the actual `O` type in the code of the `Controller` class.

Using the `Callback<Any>` may require to declare the `Callback` type parameters with variance. In Kotlin one defines variance at the declaration level. See 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance
for more details.